Diatomaceous earth precautions
I'm using food grade diatomaceous earth to get rid of pests in my new apartment. What are the necessary precautions other than wearing PPE?
I just applied it to my room. I used a powder duster to get under the baseboards and used a broom to sweep some into the cracks between the floorboards all around the room.
How long after applying should I leave the room and keep my pets out of the room? Sweeping seemed to kick up some dust.
Also, should I keep my laptop and other electronics away from it?
I'm sick to hell of all the vague and non-specific advice that Google pulls up on this topic. Does anyone have real information on how to use this stuff safely?

Perhaps better on the Biology Stack?

Frame challenge: It's a bit late now, but there is the question of whether diatomaceous earth was the best choice for your situation...

diatomaceous earth  is calcium carbonate ... composed of billions of dead diatoms https://duckduckgo.com/?q=diatoms&iax=images&ia=images ... the dust has sharp edges, which scratches insects ... the fans in your laptop might self-destruct if exposed to the powder

Food grade diatomaceous earth is non-toxic; it works by drying the exoskeletons of bugs to the point of dehydration and death. I wouldn't worry about animal accidentally ingesting it; it is often used as an anti-caking agent in animal food.
I'm pretty sure that any particulates inhaled long term is bad for humans, so it makes me cautious on short term inhalation as well. Once the dust is settled, I think it you would be fine to inhabit the area as normal.
As far as electronics, non-fan cooled are not something I would worry about, but fan cooled, like your laptop, might pull in dust and make it less efficient. Just don't put your laptop on a pile of the stuff and you should be fine.
You should contact the manufacturer with your concerns.
Here is a sample SDS for a brand of food grade DE.

I agree with all of the above advice, but would like to add that it has been proven that proper pest control begins with treatment outside, so pests do not get into the building.  If this is your home, explore exterior treatments.  If an apartment or condo building, express your issues with the management company. It is their responsibility to provide pest control.

@RMDman I think that entirely depends on the pest. Bed bugs and fleas can't be controlled from the exterior. Roaches and other bugs can be with proper sealing, but if you already have them, you'd need to still treat the inside. Sealing the exterior is always a good idea though.

Okay, but none of this answers my question about how long to evacuate the room after applying it. I can't even see the damn dust, how do I know whether it's settled?

@user288725 Hard to say as it depends on the particle sizes. According to 3M and Wikipedia, it could range from 15 minutes to 48 hours for extremely fine particles. 15 minutes seems like it is all it would generally take given the typical particle size of DE, but possibly as long as 12 hours.

https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/1934851O/3m-anz-rpd-fit-test-poster-particle-hang-time.pdf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatomaceous_earth#:~:text=It%20has%20a%20particle%20size,result%20of%20its%20high%20porosity.
